# Bootstrap input-group-addon alignment issue when a span is added for required asterisks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following Bootstrap datepicker. When I added a span (`spanAstreisk`) to display an asterisk indicating a required field, the height of icons is increased and it looks like it is not aligned with the textbox. How can I fix this?

**Fiddle2**: https://jsfiddle.net/ezvzvvqg/15/

**Fiddle1**: https://jsfiddle.net/ezvzvvqg/10/

[image]
[image]

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-user-information" style="font-size:12px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdPopupTextDescription">Effective Date:</td>
            <td id="tdEffectiveDate">          
                <div id="divDatePickerEffectiveDate" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-show-on-focus="true">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required error" id="txtEffectiveDate" maxlength="10" style="display:inline;">
                    <label for="txtEffectiveDate" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716703/display-errors-from-jquery-validate-in-different-containers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you put a `<label>` inside the `input-group` but only `input-group-addon`, `input-group-btn` and `form-control` should be inside the `input-group`. That `<label>` is forcing the icons to stretch to accommodate the label. So I removed the `<label>` and put it outside the `input-group`. After I did that, the asterisk addon worked fine.

Here is a fiddle with my changes: https://jsfiddle.net/ezvzvvqg/18/

Here it is in Stack Snippet form:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-user-information" style="font-size:12px;">
    <tbody>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="tdPopupTextDescription">Effective Date:</td>
            <td id="tdEffectiveDate">          
                <div id="divDatePickerEffectiveDate" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-show-on-focus="true">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required error" id="txtEffectiveDate" maxlength="10" style="display:inline;">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><span id="spanAstreisk" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
                <label for="txtEffectiveDate" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:** I noticed that you had one other asterisk without `input-group-addon`. If you want the asterisk without the style of an `input-group-addon`, then you can use a span and then apply styles that will make it act like a `input-group-addon`. The style declarations that you need are: `display:table-cell`, `vertical-align-middle` (these two styles make the asterisk vertically-centered) and `width:1%` (to make it take the least amount of space). Plus `padding:6px 12px` to give it the same spacing as the addons. Here is a demo:

```css
#spanAstreisk {
  display:table-cell;
  width:1%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-user-information" style="font-size:12px;">
    <tbody>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="tdPopupTextDescription">Effective Date:</td>
            <td id="tdEffectiveDate">          
                <div id="divDatePickerEffectiveDate" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-show-on-focus="true">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required error" id="txtEffectiveDate" maxlength="10" style="display:inline;">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span id="spanAstreisk" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk"></span>
                </div>
                <label for="txtEffectiveDate" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here's the new code**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdPopupTextDescription">Effective Date:
        </td>
        <td id="tdEffectiveDate">
            <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-show-on-focus="true">
                <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="txtEffectiveDate" maxlength="10" style="display:inline;">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span id="test" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-addon spanAstreisk">
                    <span id="spanAstreisk" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.spanAstreisk{
    background:none;
    border:0
}
```

Look at this solution: jsfiddle.net/SeniorFront/z24cc91a

Comment: This causes new issues. https://jsfiddle.net/ezvzvvqg/16/. Please check my updated question

Answer (score 2):

You just need a bit of positioning:

```
#spanAstreisk{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

**Update:**

The label you had inside of the input group is the actual problem, not the asterisk. At least not in the latest fiddle that you have.

The label changes the flow and alignment of input and the icon. You can break it out of flow with absolute positioning:

```
#divDatePickerEffectiveDate label{
    position: absolute; left: 0; 
    bottom: -25px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7512wj48/

Comment: The asterisks is aligned to the top now.. I need it to be aligned in center

Comment: Then change to top: 10px; ?

Comment: Or add line-height:1 like in other .glyphicon

Comment: @Lijo Updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Working example**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
              

           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
           
           <table>
 <tr>
    <td class="tdPopupTextDescription">Effective Date:
    </td>
     <td id="tdEffectiveDate">
      <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-show-on-focus="true">
       <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="txtEffectiveDate" maxlength="" style="display:inline;">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group-addon">
             <span id="test" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk"></span>
       </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="height: 20px;">
           <span id="spanAstreisk" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk" style="position: absolute;top:10px;"></span>   
       </div>
        
     </div>
     
   </td>
   </tr>

 </table>
           </body>
           </html>
```

If you need only one asterix you can achieve it like this

**One asterix example**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
              

           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
           
           <table>
 <tr>
    <td class="tdPopupTextDescription">Effective Date:
    </td>
     <td id="tdEffectiveDate">
      <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-show-on-focus="true">
       <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="txtEffectiveDate" maxlength="" style="display:inline;">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
       </div>
       
        <div class="input-group" style="height: 20px;">
           <span id="spanAstreisk" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk" style="position: absolute;top:10px;"></span>   
       </div>
        
     </div>
     
   </td>
   </tr>

 </table>
           </body>
           </html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need the asterisks at the end as per my requirement document

Comment: I have updated the answer check if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of correct answers here so a different approach would be to put the asterisk inside the input field to indicate that the field is mandatory.

```js
$("#txtEffectiveDate").on("focus",function(){
$( "#spanAstreisk" ).animate({
    opacity: 1
  },600);
$("#spanAstreisk").css("opacity",1);
}).on("blur",function(){
$( "#spanAstreisk" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  },600);
});
```

```css
#spanAstreisk {
  position:absolute;
  top:1rem;
  right:4.5rem;
  opacity:.25;
  z-index:9999;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<table>
 <tr>
    <td class="tdPopupTextDescription">Effective Date:
    </td>
     <td id="tdEffectiveDate">
      <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-show-on-focus="true">
       <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="txtEffectiveDate" maxlength="10" style="display:inline;">
       <span id="spanAstreisk" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk"></span>
       <div class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
       </div>       
     </div>
   </td>
   </tr>
 
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add some css, working with position and here is the result

https://jsfiddle.net/e1sue1ym/

```
`.input-group.date {
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.input-group.date label.error {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -23px;
  left: 0;
}
.input-group .requiredAsterisk {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}`
```

Is that what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-user-information" style="font-size:12px;">
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td class="tdPopupTextDescription">Effective Date:</td>
            <td id="tdEffectiveDate">          
                <div id="divDatePickerEffectiveDate" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-show-on-focus="true">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required error" id="txtEffectiveDate" maxlength="10" style="display:inline;">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><span id="spanAstreisk" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk requiredAsterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
                <label for="txtEffectiveDate" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And for your stylesheet

----- Stylesheet ----

```
#sizing-addon1{
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding:2px 5px;
  color:#C00
}
```

Comment: @Lijo looking for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to add the following style to the astrisk span:

```
#spanAstreisk {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is your updated fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezvzvvqg/21/)